# How do you trigger search in iPad OS from anywhere without an external keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados

I know this is possible because I keep accidentally bringing up Spotlight Search randomly when I’m using apps. Not on the Home Screen.

I’ve searched and all I can find is that you can trigger the search either from the Home Screen, with an external keyboard, or with a11y controls and that there’s no other way.

If there’s a gesture for this I’d love to know what it is because I would actually use that.
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) iPadOS 14.4.2

- I’ve never used an external keyboard
- I use the Apple Folio Case
- I use an Apple Pencil
- I’ve been having issues with phantom touches near the corner of the volume keys side and USB port side
- It usually happens somehow when, in landscape, my hand is near the top left of the screen but I can’t reproduce it afterwards

Comment: Spotlight/search can be brought up on an iPad/iPhone by swiping down from the middle of the screen **when you are on a home screen.** As far as I can see that gesture does not work while you are **in** an app.

Comment: I can access search within an app if I first swipe down from the top (open Notification Center) and then swipe to the right on my iPhone. I think it worked on my iPad too a few years ago until I disabled it in settings. I cannot recall which setting it was. Does it work for you?

Comment: @iTunes that gets me to the widgets but there doesn't seem to be a search there

Comment: I'm with you, Dude. I've done it by accident before myself, and have not been able to figure out what triggers it.

Comment: @Calion Finally figured it out in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to trigger search without an external keyboard.

Turns out it's contextual and only works after a specific action.

It's the "← Search" text that appears in the top left corner of the screen after you get to an App via iPadOS Search.

[image: iPad OS Search Text on the left side of the Status bar to trigger the Search overlay]

If you accidentally tap it the Search overlay will appear. However, the "← Search" text will disappear meaning you can't tap it a second time to reproduce it.

If you leave the App and then get into it again via Search the "← Search" text will once again appear and let you trigger the search overlay.

You can click for a Video Demonstration below:

[image: Video Demonstration]